# Integral solution of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

I'm having difficulty verifying that $$K(x)=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-xt}}{\sqrt{t^{2}-1}}\, dt$$

satisfies the differential equation $$f^{\prime\prime}\left(x\right)+\frac{1}{x}f^{\prime}\left(x\right)-f\left(x\right)=0$$

I've tried evaluating each of the terms in the differential equation using $K(x)$ in place of $f(x)$ and then summing them as in the differential equation to see if it equaled zero, but when I do that, I always wind up with the exact same sum that I started with.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried differentiation under the integral sign? [Here is a link.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

Comment: Yes, I did.  I obtained $$F^{\prime\prime}\left(z\right)=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{t^{2}e^{-zt}}{\sqrt{t^{2}-1}}\, dt$$ and $$\frac{F^{\prime}\left(z\right)}{x}=\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-xt}\sqrt{t^{2}-1}\, dt$$ after plugging in the limits of integration, but even when using that, I wasn't able to verify the result.  I've tried integrating these terms by parts and combining them as well as integrating some while leaving other terms in their pre-integrated form, but it hasn't worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g(t,x) = \exp(-t x) \left(1-t^2\right)^{-1/2}$. Note that
$$
    \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} g(t,x) + \frac{1}{x} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} g(t,x) - g(t,x) \stackrel{\text{evaluate}}{=} \exp(-t x)  \frac{-t-x(1-t^2)}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left( \exp(-t x) \sqrt{1-t^2} \right) 
$$
Now $f(x) = \int_1^\infty g(t,x) \mathrm{d}t$ giving:
$$ 
    f^{\prime\prime}(x) + \frac{1}{x} f^\prime(x) - f(x) = \left. \exp(-t x) \sqrt{1-t^2}  \right|_{t \to 1^+}^{t \to \infty}
$$
The right-hand-side vanishes for $\Re(x)>0$, which is incidentally the same condition when $\int_1^\infty g(t,x)\,\mathrm{d}t$ converges, thus establishing the claim.

By the way, function $K(x)$ defined by the integral is the [modified Bessel function of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions_%3a_I.CE.B1.2C_K.CE.B1) of order $0$.